# how to update the list view after deletion data from list?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

i am new to android.There is a listView in my application in which there is a list of questions and i want to update that list dynamically when i delete any question from it.please help.

```
public class admin extends Activity {
static int itemPosition;
ListView lv;
List<Question> quesList2;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.admin);
    lv=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    QuizHelper db = new QuizHelper(this);  // my question bank class
    quesList2 = db.getAllQuestions2();
    int a= quesList2.size();
    String[] testArray = new String[a];
    for (int i = 0; i < testArray.length; i++) {
        testArray[i]=quesList2.get(i).getQUESTION();
    }
    ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,     
    android.R.id.text1,testArray);

    // Assign adapter to ListView
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    registerForContextMenu(lv);
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                                int position, long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            itemPosition     = position;
        }
    });
}
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,  
ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo)
{
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Delete");//groupId, itemId, order, title
}
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item){
    QuizHelper db = new QuizHelper(this);
    if(item.getTitle()=="Delete"){
     db.deleteDB();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Successfully deleted", 
    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        lv.invalidateViews();
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
    return true;
 }

 }
```

here is the delete function which is in the databasehelper.java class.

```
protected void deleteDB(){
    dbase = this.getWritableDatabase();
    dbase.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + TABLE_QUEST + " WHERE " + KEY_ID + " =  
  '"+admin.itemPosition+"'");
 }
```

Comment: notifyDataSetChanged() after removing

Comment: You can also use Recycler View  and it has a method for item removal
recyclerAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(position);

Comment: see [here](https://github.com/Miserlou/Android-SDK-Samples/tree/master/NotePad) for a sample code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use **[notifyDataSetChanged()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged())**

> Notifies the attached observers that the underlying data has been
>   changed and any View reflecting the data set should refresh itself.

**Code**

```
if(item.getTitle()=="Delete"){
 db.deleteDB();
 adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get away with `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged` but this doesn't make sure that your data is actually deleted! there might be error while having database operation!

A cleaner approach will be setting a custom listener and notify the view from database class that it was a successful operation.

Create a interface,

```
public interface DatabaseListener {
    void deleteSuccess();
    void deleteError();
}
```

Assign listener to be notified,

```
public class admin extends Activity implements DatabaseListener{
...your codes
//you need to implement the interface methods

@Override
public void deleteSuccess(){
  adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
  Toast.makeText(this, "Successfully deleted",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
public void deleteError(){
  Toast.makeText(this, "Failed to delete",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}


}
```

Notify listener,

```
protected void deleteDB(){
    dbase = this.getWritableDatabase();
    try {
        dbase.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + TABLE_QUEST + " WHERE " + KEY_ID + " ='"+admin.itemPosition+"'");
        //verify if the data is deleted
        //get the databaseListener object from your Database class constructor.

        databaseListener.deleteSuccess();
    }catch(Exception e){
        databaseListener.deleteError();
    }
}
```

Comment: Good to see you here `Asif vai` tough I was looking for some `React` stuff. Thanks.

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron Interesting!! the world is small.

Comment: Absolutely true. Hope you are doing great.

Answer (score 0):

wherever you are calling the

```
 deleteDB()
```

method, call

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
```

after that

Answer (score 0):

Please consider to use recyclerview instead of list view.

here is a fantastic guide if you don't know how to use it: https://guides.codepath.com/android/using-the-recyclerview